# JS/MongoDB: Check if nested field is existing in a object (collection document)

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I need to check if there is a field `content` exisiting by the document id and the nested element which will be identified also by an id.

Therefore I take the document by `Collection.findOne({ _id: 'dZXr2Pg7Ak4M5aYWF'})`, which gives me this:

```
{
    "_id" : "dZXr2Pg7Ak4M5aYWF",
    "points" : [
        {
            "id" : "Gwf5BzorXyYBZSEzK",
            "coordinates" : [
                433,
                215
            ],
            "content" : "anything"
        },
        {
            "id" : "iwSM98W5PD87BtcLa",
            "coordinates" : [
                666,
                186
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

No I need to check if there is a `content` field for the given `id`, that means:

```
id = 'Gwf5BzorXyYBZSEzK' -> true
id = 'iwSM98W5PD87BtcLa' -> false
```

I also tried to get this information directly by `findOne`:

```
Collection.findOne({ 
    _id: 'dZXr2Pg7Ak4M5aYWF', 
    points: { 
        id: id, 
        content: { $exists: true } 
    } 
});
```

But this gives me just `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Collection.findOne({ _id: 'dZXr2Pg7Ak4M5aYWF', }).points.filter(function (obj) { 
    return obj.id == id; 
})[0]).content ? true : false;
```

Answer (score -2):

An example would be:

```
Collection.findOne({_id: 'dZXr2Pg7Ak4M5aYWF'},function(err, doc) {
    if (doc.points.content){
        console.log(true);
    } else {
        console.log(false);
    }
});
```

Comment: No because it doesnt Take id in consideration. There are Multiple points.

Comment: @user3142695 oups yes you are right i missed the question,i didnt see the nested ids.